# How to have different routes ids on different routes for the same resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have never found a good solution for this problem. I have the following routes structure:

```
resources :contents

namespace :admin do
  resources :contents
end
```

When I call `content_path(content)` I want the id to be the slug of the content, while when I call `admin_content_path(content)` I want the id to be the id of the content. I just want the id not to be related to the model (actually the id is the returning value of the `to_param` method of the model), but to the route.

I would like to avoid defining helper methods for every route, it's a weak solution in my opinion.

I know I can write `admin_content_path(id: content.id)` or `content_path(id: content.slug)`, but this is just an hack actually. Also, this is especially annoying in `form_for`, since I can't write

```
form_for @content
```

but I'm forced to use

```
form_for @content, url: @content.new_record? ? admin_contents_path : admin_contents_path(id: @content.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would change the route to:

```
resources :contents, param: :slug
```

and then you override `to_param` method to become:

```
class Content < ApplicationRecord
  def to_param
    slug
  end
end
```

And finally in your controller, you replace `Content.find(params[:id]` with `Content.find_by(slug: params[:slug])`.

That will give you URLs like `/contents/foo-bar` when you call `content_path(content)`.

In your case, you can additionally create a subclass that overrides the `to_param` method:

```
module Admin
  class Content < ::Content
    def to_param
      id && id.to_s # This is the default for ActiveRecord
    end
  end
end
```

Since your `admin/contents_controller.rb` is namespaced under `Admin` (e.g `Admin::ContentsController`), it will by default use the `Admin::Content` class instead of the normal `Content` class, and thus the object itself and all routes should be as you like them to be, including forms.

Comment: Hi, nice solution! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would say that's two different problems : URL generation for your resources on the user front-end side (using slugs) and URL generation for your admin forms.

Obviously in your admin, you will never be able to just write `form_for @resource` because your admin is namespaced, so the minimum would at least be `form_for [:admin, @resource]`.

Let's say you have `to_param` on some of your models to return a slug, you may create your own customised helpers on your admin back-office to always return a path namespaced to `/admin/` and using the `id` of the record.

One generic way to do that is adding this kind of code in your `Admin` root controller.

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController

  helper_method :admin_resource_path, :edit_admin_resource_path

  def admin_resource_path(resource)
    if resource.new_record?
      polymorphic_path([:admin, ActiveModel::Naming.route_key(resource)])
    else
      polymorphic_path([:admin, ActiveModel::Naming.singular_route_key(resource)], id: resource.id)
    end
  end

  def edit_admin_resource_path(resource)
    polymorphic_path([:edit, :admin, ActiveModel::Naming.singular_route_key(resource)], id: resource.id)
  end
end
```

Then in your form you can use `form_for(@user, url: admin_resource_path(@user)`. It will work on both user creation and user edition.
You will be able to use those helpers also in your controllers to redirect...

Comment: I would like to avoid defining helper methods for every route

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a nice solution, but only on Rails >= 5.1 (which is in rc1 at the moment), using the brand new [`direct` method](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/CustomUrls.html#method-i-direct):

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :contents
end

# Maps admin content paths in order to use model.id instead of model.to_param
{ admin_content: :show, edit_admin_content: :edit }.each do |direct_name, action|
  direct direct_name do |model, options|
    options.merge(controller: 'admin/contents', action: action, id: model.id)
  end
end
```